# Change Product Key

Tags: licensing

I installed MS Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition with one product key.
Now I need to change product key to another. Is it possible?

I tried to change key throw Central Administration, it was unsuccessful.

Many people in the internet recommend to reinstall Sharepoint, but it's unacceptably for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the product key in any supported manner.  In general, Microsoft doesn't care what product key is in use as long as you hold a valid license.  But if you feel you have to change the key, you'll need to re-install SharePoint and leverage a new Configuration database.