# is it applicable to change the key of SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

I am using an enterprise key for SharePoint that is not trail and also not my own , but I need to change it to my own license key

Is it applicable?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the product key in any supported manner. In general, Microsoft doesn't care what product key is in use as long as you hold a valid license. But if you feel you have to change the key, you'll need to re-install SharePoint and leverage a new Configuration database.

Credit goes to @Trevor Seward 
[link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58801/change-product-key)